# Input field doesn't get cleared after choosing the value in the ExtJS tag field

Tags: extjs, extjs6, tagfield

I have the ExtJS tag field with anyMatch = true. Now if you type **AB** it will show the result and once you choose the selection it will clear the input you have entered i.e. **AB** Now when you have anyMatch= true that time if I type **HI** it will show you the result but when you choose the value the input field doesn't get cleared. I saw the ExtJS Tag field code it is handled explicitly in **clearInput** method. I wanted to know why this is implemented in this way ?
Below is the sample code

```
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Tag Field Example',
    width: 1000,
    bodyPadding: 10,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        labelWidth: 100,
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            defaults: {
                flex: 1,
            },
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{

                xtype: 'tagfield',
                minChars: 1,
                anyMatch: true,
                allowBlank: true,
                margin: '5 5 5 5',
                fieldLabel: 'Tag Field 1',
                name: 'tagField1',
                store: ['ABC D', 'EFG HI', 'C'],
                queryMode: 'local',
                filterPickList: true,
                emptyText: 'Multi Select...'
            }]
        }]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. If you take a look at the `clearInput` method from the [tagfield class definition](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/src/Tag.js.html), and specifically at the section with the early return:

```
if (!Ext.String.startsWith(lastDisplayValue, inputValue, true)) {
    return;
}
```

You can see that they discard clearing of the field if the last selected tag field value does not start with the typed input value ('abc d' starts with 'ab' so the field is cleared; 'efg hi' does not start with 'hi' - so the clearing is discarded).

This will clearly not work when you have the [anyMatch](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#cfg-anyMatch) config enabled.

The early return section from above, should be something like this:

```
if (!me.anyMatch) {
    if (!Ext.String.startsWith(lastDisplayValue, inputValue, true)) {
        return;
    }
} else {
    if (lastDisplayValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        return;
    }
}
```

We keep the initial check when `anyMatch` is not enabled, otherwise, we check if the typed input values **is included** in the last selected tag field value.

Here is a fiddle with the proposed override: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32q0

Comment: Yes, I have seen this. I wanted to know if there are some intentions behind doing this ????

Comment: I think this is an omission. Tag field inherits the `anyMatch` config from the combobox field. I guess they have added support for the combo first, but then forgot to update the tag field class to also support this.

Answer (score 0):

I used arrays for multi string values (list item: Lincoln Abraham, input value: Abraham Lin).
That way method to checks if it matches properly.
In my implenmentation last part of the input string is used as wildcarded string. It also solves the problem where list item is reversed compare to input string, which was in my case.

```
   clearInput: function() {
    var me = this,
      valueRecords = me.getValueRecords(),
      inputValue = me.inputEl && me.inputEl.dom.value,
      lastDisplayValue;
    if (valueRecords.length && inputValue) {
      lastDisplayValue = valueRecords[valueRecords.length - 1].get(me.displayField);

      let inputValueArr = inputValue.split(' ');
      let lastDisplayValueArr = lastDisplayValue.split(' ');
      let matchCount = 0;
      Ext.each(inputValueArr, function(iv, idx1, arr1) {
        Ext.each(lastDisplayValueArr, function(ldv, idx1, arr2) {
          if (!me.anyMatch) {
            if (Ext.String.startsWith(ldv, iv, true)) {
              matchCount++;
            }
          } else {
            if (ldv.toLowerCase().indexOf(iv.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
              matchCount++;
            }
          }
        });
      });
      if (matchCount < inputValueArr.length) {
        return;
      }
      me.inputEl.dom.value = '';
      if (me.queryMode === 'local') {
        me.clearLocalFilter();
        // we need to refresh the picker after removing
        // the local filter to display the updated data
        me.getPicker().refresh();
      }
    }
  }
```